# /bin/sh: zypper: not found (Docker)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, opensuse, docker-build

I am trying to create and image. But when I run `docker build`. I keep getting the error:

```
Step 6/7 : RUN zypper update && zypper upgrade -y && zypper install -y git
 ---> Running in 81e84f3be4f0
/bin/sh: zypper: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c zypper update && zypper upgrade -y && zypper install -y git' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

First I was getting something similar with `git` not being found. So after a bit of Googling, i found out that I probably need to install `git` in the docker file.

So I added something like:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4 AS maven
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine

RUN mkdir -p $HOME/images/lib/ && cd $HOME/images/lib/

RUN zypper update && zypper upgrade -y && zypper install -y git

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git

RUN git clone MY_GIT_URL
```

But it errors out on the second line.

My Docker info is :

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 9
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 9
 Images: 8
 Server Version: 20.10.17-ce
 Storage Driver: btrfs
  Build Version: Btrfs v4.15
  Library Version: 102
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux oci runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-ga916309fff0f
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.14.21-150400.24.33-default
 Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.4
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 9.714GiB
 Name: localhost.localdomain
 ID: U76D:CEPC:3L3J:ZTTL:C5UQ:TOEZ:DLXA:5NQQ:HOQ7:SHRC:KXBZ:HLJE
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: MY_USERNAME
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: What base image do you use? Can you append the whole Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidL. I have updated the whole thing. I am learning it as I go along. So I have only up to this for now.

Comment: Why don't you pick the update image, https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/tags?page=1&name=3.8.4? I can see it's published 9 months ago

Comment: @DreamBold I got it from an example I found online, when I started off. But it fetching the image just fine. Might be an deprecated image?
Is this the right one to use?
`FROM maven:3-amazoncorretto-19`

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/maven/3.8.6-eclipse-temurin-11-alpine/images/sha256-0cc8ec0a8fe3f53cd71f7f84cef1ff271cd270a8dfaebf7b9e0033510de2584d?context=explore
This seems to be the lastet version, am not sure if you need `temurin` version 11.

Comment: `FROM maven:3.8.6 AS maven
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine` You can just update the version to 3.8.6, and try again

Comment: If the latest version doesn't have `zypper`, you'll need to install it manually from the online repo or try full version of the image without `alpine` as it's a minimum package

Comment: `FROM maven:3.8.6 AS maven
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jdk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container image `eclipse-temurin:11-jdk-alpine` is based on Alpine Linux, not Suse. Thus, to install operating system packages, use `apk` instead of `zypper`. For example:

```
RUN apk update && apk add git
```

Comment: Yeah. I just realized that the image of the provider is more important than the OS I run on. That worked out just fine. But just one curious question, how do I know what an image is built on?

Comment: Great question. Some Docker image authors indicate in the tag name, like `-alpine`, or provide info in their docs. Otherwise, you can start up the container and run `cat /etc/*-release`. Another way is to look at the original `Dockerfile` if that's possible.